# junk characters from stdin after reading from file in C

Tags: c, file-io, stdin, scanf

After succesfully reading a re-directed file to my program from the console, I ask a user to enter a word, then use scanf() to read in the word.

The problem i'm having is that scanf() is immediately reading in junk characters and then the program continues. It doesn't even pause to let the user enter anything in the console. It doesn't happen when I don't open a file. EVERYTHING else works perfectly. What could be the issue:

**I tried everything suggested, still can't get it to work. I've made a new project that is just for getting this part to work, here it is. Ignore that scanf is only looking for a single character, even though I ask for a word. I did this just to see if the program would actually pause and allow me to enter something, but it doesn't. Just enters some garbage and program ends.

```
 main(){

       int n,i;
       char ch;
       char line[80];

       while(fgets(line, 80, stdin) != NULL){
         for(i=0;i<80;i++){
            ch=line[i];
            if(ch=='\n'){
                printf("%c",ch);
                break;
            }
            else{
                    printf("%c",ch);
            }
         }
       }
       printf("Please enter a word: ");
       scanf("%c",&ch);
    }
```

Comment: Please try putting some whitespace around some of your punctuation. Your code almost looks like a decryption gone wrong... :(

Answer (score 2):

You can't re-direct stdin from a file and then also use the keyboard for input (that I know of).  If you want to do that, it's simpler to have the program take the input file as a command-line argument and then run it like so:  `prog myfile.txt`.  Also, leave yourself a pad with fgets() -- use one less than the allocated array for maxlen.  It's always safest with C char arrays to use one less than the allocated length for anything requiring a maximum length in case the maximum length is not including the '\0' terminating character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])

       {
       FILE *f;
       int i;
       char line[80];

       if (argc<2)
           {
           printf("Usage:  %s <inputfile>\n",argv[0]);
           exit(10);
           }
       /* Open file and echo to stdout */
       f=fopen(argv[1],"r");
       if (f==NULL)
           {
           printf("Cannot open file %s for input.\n",argv[1]);
           exit(20);
           }
       while (fgets(line, 79, f) != NULL)
           printf("%s",line);
       fclose(f);

       /* Get user input from stdin */
       printf("Please enter a word: ");
       if (fgets(line,79,stdin)==NULL)
           {
           printf("Nothing entered.  Program aborted.\n");
           exit(30);
           }
       /* Remove CR/LF from end of line */
       for (i=strlen(line)-1;i>=0 && (line[i]=='\n' || line[i]=='\r');i--)
           ;
       line[i+1]='\0';
       printf("The word entered is: '%s'\n",line);
       return(0);
       }
```

Comment: +1 for the 'pay attention to your compiler warnings'.  People  (especially beginners) tend to forget that the compiler knows a lot more about C than they do, and the compiler will help you improve your C if you ask it to.  With GCC, you should routinely compile with `-Wall`; I use `-Wall -Wextra -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition` and expect my code to compile with zero warnings (sometimes enforced by adding `-Werror`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler -- Amen to that.  There is nothing quite so satisfying as compiling a large bit of code with no warnings.

Comment: OK. I changed it as suggested, it works when I open the file manually from the source code. But when I change the code to read from stdin and then redirect the same file to the program from the command line, it's doing the same thing as before, and not pausing to allow the user to enter any data, and is printing garbage characters. So same as before, but now only when I redirect the file from the command line and read from stdin

Comment: @user2845183 -- You need to check your second fscanf for a zero result (no string found).  If you are redirecting from a file, I suggest using fgets to get a line from stdin.  Then check the return value for NULL.  That means you are at the end of your redirected file.  Otherwise, use sscanf on the character buffer read by fgets.

Comment: edited original post. Please help! I can't figure this out for the life of me!

Comment: @user2845183 -- answer modified.

Comment: "Leave yourself a pad with [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html)?" How about, "make sure you know which functions will account for the terminal null, and which won't"? The `fgets()` function is specified to always return a properly null-terminated string that fits into the buffer, so if you tell it the buffer is smaller than it really is, you're pointlessly wasting memory.

Comment: It's not always clear from documentation, and I don't always want to spend the time to look it up, so I always use the allocated array size minus one for maxlen on any C string function that takes such an argument.  I'd rather save a few seconds than a few bytes.

Answer (score 0):

sscanf is used to input from a stream or a buffer, and in unix stdin is considered as file so u are supposed to use fscanf which inputs from a file so use fscanf(stdin,"%s",testword);

Comment: The standard uses the term 'streams' to refer to file streams or `FILE *`.  `sscanf()` is not used with file streams but with character buffers.  The standard says of `sscanf()`: _The `sscanf` function is equivalent to `fscanf`, except that input is obtained from a string (specified by the argument `s`) rather than from a stream._